# SQLServer connection with PowerShell Issue setting ConnectionTimeout Property

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm connecting to SQLServer database using PowerShell. My script running a SQL code works fine but periodically it fails generating desired output and then running it again works fine.

```
$mySQLQuery = "SQL Query Here"

$myDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet "myDataResultSet"
    $sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=myDBServer;Integrated Security = False; User ID = UserName; Password =PassWord;")
    $SqlConn.ConnectionTimeout= 0
    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($mySQLQuery, $sqlConn)
$adapter.Fill($myDataSet)
$SqlConn.Close()
```

While, searching and reading I found that it has something to do with connection timeout. I tried to set sql connection timeout to 0 from default 30 but while running the scirpt I'm getting error saying below:

```
$sqlConn.ConnectionTimeout = 0  is read-only property.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks will try this in case below suggestion doesn't work. Appreicate your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to fix this is to add `;Connection Timeout=60` to your connect string.

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection('Connection Timeout=60')
$sqlConn.ConnectionTimeout
60
```

you probably don't want it set to 0, use 300 or something if you need a ridiculously high value.

Comment: Thanks will try this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I set the *Command* Timeout, rather than the connection...

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "<yourconnectionstring>"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = "<yoursql>"
$command.CommandTimeout = 0

$results = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$table.Load($results)

$connection.Dispose()
```